# How to Make Asyc Approach

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie to XMLHHTP and I just made the code below with some online help from some people and realized that I need to make it async as there are hundreds of URLs that the workbook needs to visit.

I would truly appreciate if someone could look into this and turn it into an async.

```
Sub GetInfo()

    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sdd As String
    Dim add As Variant
    Dim url As Range

    i = 2

    For Each url In Range(Cells(3, "J"), Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
        With Http
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        sdd = Html.querySelector("span[itemprop='price']").getAttribute("content")
        i = i + 1
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "K") = sdd

    Next url


End Sub
```

Comment: When you say async, you mean background processing or not blocking ui? There is a difference.

Comment: Hi Skin, thank you for looking into this. This is what I thought `async` can do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTtZd.gif

Comment: Have a read of this article ... https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2800327/limitation-of-asynchronous-programming-to-the-excel-object-model ... might help to understand Excel's async capabilities.  My only suggestion would be to look into timers to see if they can do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for directing me over to that link. I have actually read it before, and a few more resources that are more detailed than that. I must say, at my level right now, I dont know how to apply it to my worksheet. Thus, Im asking for help if someone can convert my code into `async`

Comment: I reckon you need to look at abstracting your logic to another language where you can open the workbook and run the http calls asynchronously, like a C# or something. It’s unlikely to give you the ui experience you want though, that’d be the downside.

Comment: Is that another way of saying its not possible with just excel alone? Im optimistic that it is possible, especially when the gif from my previous comment has demonstrated it. That gif was taken from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185212/a-new-approach-to-multithreading-in-excel

Comment: I'm sure someone else out there knows but maybe look at Application.OnTime and see if that works for you.  Alternatively, drop me a list of the URL's your'e wanting to query and I'll see if I can get that theory tested.

Comment: Sure thing. There are two base websites. Realtor.com and homesnap.com. There are addresses in columns C to F which contains the street, city, state, and zipcode respectively. I concatenate them altogether then add in realtor.com to it to form a URL which then populates column J. Its not always leading to the correct website and I dont know why. But anyway, most of the URLs work like https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/2912-W-1st-St-Apt-1_Jacksonville_FL_32254_M64890-70026 and https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/811-W-Main-St_Oblong_IL_62449_M86349-98322

Comment: Those are for realtor.com. I figure if it works, I can somehow replicate it to work with the other websites like homesnap.com. Thank you so much for giving it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your answer, look at this walkthrough ...

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Skin,  I will check on it.